# Finding where the last save location is recorded in Acrobat?

Tags: windows, adobe-acrobat, default-profile

I have a couple, Adobe Acrobat DC (2020) (Win10) scanning stations that are used by a lot of workers who must scan to a particular network path.  Thus, I need every user to have the default save location in Acrobat to be that path.

According to many Adobe discussion boards (e.g. [this one](https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat-discussions/default-save-location-in-dc/m-p/7194478)), there is no way to set that default save location (despite many years of users begging for the option -- Thanks Adobe!).  I appreciate that there is no "official" way, but the last open/save location must be saved somewhere, so I set out to find it with the hope of copying it to the default user profile.

Since it is a per-user value, I started a new profile and had it open/save a single document in Acrobat to a uniquely-named location and now Acrobat "remembers" to start the open/save dialog there.  The next step was to identify where that path is being referenced.  The path shows up in a number of registry keys for various reasons, but removing/changing the path everywhere I find it has no affect on the path Acrobat starts in for the open/save dialog.  I've completely eliminated everything Adobe-adjacent in HKCU and in the appdata tree just to get back to the default open/save path, and the last one I used still appears when I open Acrobat again.

Where else could that path possibly be stored for an unprivileged user?

Comment: Are there Adobe folders in AppData? Perhaps the value is being stored in some config file there and not in the registry.

Comment: There are Adobe folders in AppData.  However, if I delete those folders (in Local, LocalLow and Roaming), Acrobat still remembers the location.  If I delete both those and the Adobe registry keys in HKCU, Acrobat *still* remembers the location.  Where else could it be?

Comment: What are the specific registry keys you've looked at in testing this?

Comment: I removed the entire `HKCU\Software\Adobe` key, and every other registry entry under `HKCU` with "Acrobat" or "Adobe" except the ones related to default apps.  Acrobat still opened the save dialog to the last save location.  The unique path does not appear in the registry (in plaintext) outside that Adobe key at all.